How can I run a tkinter application to allow pyautogui locateOnScreen function to process?
The frame appears at the top of the screen, but although I am using update_idletasks(), the buttons do not appear before the locateOnScreen function is called
If I include update(), then the buttons do appear. However, the _locate_button call in main does not find the button
The button is found if I comment out the _locate_button call in main and click on Search
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import pyautogui

def main() -> None:
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Locate button')
    root.geometry('300x200+0+0')

    button = ttk.Button(root, text='Search', command=_locate_button)
    button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

    button = ttk.Button(root, text='Exit', underline=1,)
    button.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

    root.update_idletasks()
    root.update()

    _locate_button()

    root.mainloop()

def _locate_button():
    # pos = button.winfo_geometry()
    pos = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('exit_button.png')
    print(pos)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

I know that I can find the location using winfo_geometry, but I am trying to establish the principle using pyautogui
System details:
Operating System: Manjaro Linux 
KDE Plasma Version: 6.0.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 6.4.0
Qt Version: 6.7.2
Kernel Version: 6.6.41-1-MANJARO (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11

scrot: 1.11.1
pyautogui: 0.9.54


Cannot reproduce the issue with PyAutoGUI 0.9.54 in Windows 11.

@acw1668 -thanks. May be a scrot issue - I'll add system details to question
